# Can't access shared mailbox via EWS. 401 Unauthorized in C#

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices

I have a **shared mailbox** that I am trying to connect to in EWS. I am able to access the mailbox just fine from my Outlook 2016 instance without having to provide credentials. When I try to access it via EWS, I get the following error:

> "The request failed. The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized."

I am running this code under my AD account, which has access to this mailbox. Why would I not have access in this instance? Below is the problematic code.

```
        service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010_SP2);
        service.Url = new Uri("https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx");

        service.UseDefaultCredentials = true;

        var shared_mailbox = new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, "mailbox@mydomain.com); 
        FindItemsResults<Item> results = service.FindItems(shared_mailbox, dateTimeFilter, view); //401 is thrown here.
```

Does anyone see anything wrong or missing?

Comment: Is this an on prem exchange server? It's not O365 is it?

Comment: Yeah, it is O365.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you look at using Modern Authentication (which is what Outlook should be using also). To use the currently logged on credential you need to use the MSAL library and following https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/wiki/Integrated-Windows-Authentication

Once you have the token then use

```
 ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2016);
 service.Url = new Uri("https://outlook.office365.com/ews/exchange.asmx");
 service.Credentials = new OAuthCredentials(TokenResult.AccessToken);
 service.HttpHeaders.Add("X-AnchorMailbox", MailboxName);
```

Basic authentication is going away next year so using OAuth will be a hard requirement in the future.

Comment: Hi Glen, I agree that this should be the path forward, unfortunately this will involve more decision makers and extend the timeline beyond what is currently feasible. It should be possible to access a shared O365 mailbox through EWS, right?

Comment: If your specify the credentials in the code sure (then your using Basic Auth) , but using WIA (windows integrated Authentication) like your trying not sure . Configuring an application registration in Azure so you can use oAuth is less then 10 minutes work. Be careful because your building something that you know will fail and require code changes to fix in less then a year (liabilities etc)